# Update a single object from a database - Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

So I am trying to allow users to edit menu item prices that are in the database currently. The fields will auto-populate data into the page and users will be able to edit that data to change the price. Here is what I have. I have tried and asked many questions, but I am still lost. I have googled a lot and it helped me understand forms a bit, but I'm not able to fix it. Please let me know if you need more info.

Views.py:

```
def edit_menu(request):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }


    if request.method == 'POST':

        post=ProductModelForm(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('price') and request.POST.get('name'):
            if 'name' == Product.name:
                post.name= request.POST.get('name')
                post.price= request.POST.get('price')
                post.save()

                return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
            else: 
                return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
        else:
            return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
    else:

        return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','price'] # specify which field you need to be in the form
```

HTML:

```
<title>ACRMS - Edit Menu Price</title>
<div class = "container">
    <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}

         {% for instance in object_list %}

<input name = "name" value = "{{ instance.name }}"></input>
<input type="number" name="price" value = "{{ instance.price }}"/><br>
 {% endfor %}

    </select>


<button type ="submit">Submit Changes</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Urls.py:

```
 url('edit-menu/edit/',views.edit_menu, name='Edit Menu Item'),
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: [Use a ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current implementation, you do not need a form. Instead, update the view like this:

```
# view
def edit_single_menu(request, pk):
   if request.method == 'POST':

    post=Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.POST.get('price') and request.POST.get('name'):
        post.name= request.POST.get('name')
        post.price= request.POST.get('price')
        post.save()
        return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
     else: 
        return redirect('Edit Menu Item')


   return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)

# url
url('edit-menu/edit/<pk:id>/',views.edit_single_menu, name='edit_single_menu'),


# template (mis446/edit-menu-item.html)

<title>ACRMS - Edit Menu Price</title>
<div class = "container">
{% for instance in object_list %}
<form action = "{% url 'edit_single_menu' instance.pk %}" method = 'POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name = "name" value = "{{ instance.name }}"></input>
    <input type="number" name="price" value = "{{ instance.price }}"/><br>  
    <button type ="submit">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here I am sending individual edit to a new separated view named `edit_single_menu` and store the changes there.

### Update

New url is not meant to replace the old one. It is only to assist you to update individual product. So, you need to keep both of the urls. Also, here is an answer based on @brunodesthuilliers's suggestion:

```
# view
def edit_single_menu(request, pk):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      post=Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
      form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=post)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
   return redirect('Edit Menu Item')
```

Also, do some changes on `edit_menu` view:

```
def edit_menu(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { "object_list": queryset }
    return render(request, 'mis446/edit-menu-item.html', context)
```

And urls should look like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path

# rest of the code

path('edit-menu/edit/<int:pk>/',views.edit_single_menu, name='edit_single_menu'),
path('edit-menu/edit/',views.edit_menu, name='Edit Menu Item'),
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is that url supposed to replace the one I put in my question or come after it? I did it both ways and received errors. When I replaced it, it gave me a 404 error. Then with both of them, it says the old url has no pk argument

Comment: Bad answer. You have a ModelForm, use it, that's what it's for - submitting unvalidated unsanitized user inputs to your database is totally unsafe.

Comment: I agree, I have updated my answer @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @i.s.2951 please see the update section of the answer

Comment: @ruddra that's better indeed !-)

Comment: THANK YOU BOTH SO MUCH! It works. I have been stuck on this for days! Thank you ruddra for putting in all that time.